# Eigen Map class : mapping C-array to VectorXd pointer in an efficient way

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I need to convert a plain double C-array to a VectorXd*. I found Map class that seems to do the job but there's something I didn't understand.

```
class A {
  private:
    VectorXd *jpos_;
  public:
    int init( double *v, int len )
    {
      // Here I would like to assign v to jpos_ in an efficient way
      // (something like a pointer assignment without allocation or vector iterations)
      // Note that length of v is len
    }
};
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
int A::init( double *v, int len )
{
  jpos_ = &VectorXd::Map( v, len );
}
```

or

```
int A::init( double *v, int len )
{
  jpos_ = &Map<VectorXd>( v, len );
}
```

What's wrong?
Thanks.

Emanuele

Comment: Why VectorXd* and not VectorXd?

Comment: If you want to map using Eigen::Map, your member variable should be of type Map<VectorXd> instead of VectorXd.

Comment: This is just an example: in the real code I have a VectorXd* and I cannot change it to VectorXd

Comment: If you want to keep VectorXd*, you need to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map an array by means of `Eigen::Map`, your member `jpos_` should be of type `Eigen::Map`:

```
class A
{
private:
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> jpos_;

public:    
    A(double* v, int len) : jpos_ {v, len} {}
};
```

If you need to keep the `VectorXd`, you need to copy the values to the vector. It is a bit strange to see `VectorXd*`. It's similar like `std::vector<double>*`. I would recommend not using `VectorXd*`.

```
class A
{
private:
    Eigen::VectorXd jpos_;

public:    
    A(double* v, int len) : jpos_ {v}
    {
        for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
            jpos_(i) = v[i];
    }
};
```

EDIT:

If you really need `VectorXd*`, you can allocate one with `new` (and don't forget to `delete` it).

Comment: Maybe using Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> as jpos_ is acceptable if setting the 'pointer' to a different array using placement new doesn't involve dynamic memory allocation or vector iterations. The idea is to use init() method many times to assign different vectors along the program execution and use jpos_ as input for a special algorithm.